# New Promise is not catching up the error can we use reject and catch all together?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to fetch an api, in error case errors are not catching up.

All the time error is getting undefined even though there is an error with api

```
export default {
    setRecordList({
        commit
    }) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const resp = await axios('getRecord');
                const data = resp.data
                commit('setRecordList', data);
                resolve()
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Nothing coming", err); // Error is undefined
                reject(err);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

It should catch the error what is best way how can we resolve it ?

Comment: What `err` is totally depends on where it comes from, which is not shown. Btw this is promise constructor pattern and needs to be avoided.

Comment: I didn't get the meaning ?

Comment: My ask is simple Error is getting undefined any reason we can fix it ?

Comment: The meaning of what? The question cannot be answered. You didn't show code that is responsible for this error. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary for your problem. Search "promise constructor antipattern", you have it here and you can have it in other places, it doesn't cause the error here but means that the promises can be processed incorrectly in other places and cause a problem